# Plugin not working on MusicBrainz v1.2

Tags: python, musicbrainz

As an exercise for learning, I am trying to write a plugin for MusicBrainz that matches the `albumartistsort` to `albumartist` and `artistsort` to `artist`, as opposed to the (apparently) default of **Last Name, First Name** format it is currently using.

I am just learning about Python and therefore I am trying to use another plugin as a guide, but some important changes need to be done and that's where I probably screwed up.

When I try installing the plug in, it doesn't appear in the plugin list although it is copied to the plugin folder; and the `.pyo` file is not generated. I am guessing this is due to a compilation error, but I haven't been able to include whatever I need so I can use the `picard` module (don't know where to find it nor import it) so I can test in my python interpreter.

This is the code I have:

```
PLUGIN_NAME = "Sort Artist and Album Artist"
PLUGIN_AUTHOR = "Kevin Hernandez"
PLUGIN_DESCRIPTION = "Sorts artist/album artist by name as in Artist/Album Artist field instead of Last, First"
PLUGIN_VERSION = "0.1"
PLUGIN_API_VERSIONS = ["0.9.0", "0.10", "0.15", "0.16"]

from picard.metadata import register_album_metadata_processor
import re

def copy_albumartist_to_albumartistsort(tagger, metadata, release):
  match = re.search($not($eq(metadata["albumartistsort"],metadata["albumartist"])))
    if match:
        metadata["albumartistsort"] = metadata["albumartist"]

def copy_artist_to_artistsort(tagger, metadata, release):
  match = re.search($not($eq(metadata["artistsort"],metadata["artist"])))
    if match:
        metadata["artistsort"] = metadata["artist"]

register_album_metadata_processor(copy_albumartist_to_albumartistsort)
register_album_metadata_processor(copy_artist_to_artistsort)
```

and I also tried defining the functions as:

```
def copy_albumartist_to_albumartistsort(tagger, metadata, release):
  metadata["albumartistsort"] = metadata["albumartist"]

def copy_artist_to_artistsort(tagger, metadata, release):
  metadata["artistsort"] = metadata["artist"]
```

I must point out that I don't fully understand when these are called. I believe the plugin documentation [here](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/MusicBrainz_Picard/Plugins/API), [here](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/MusicBrainz_Picard/Documentation/Scripting) and [here](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/MusicBrainz_Picard/Tags) is not enough to follow the plugins they have there (e.g. the `search` and `match` methods they use in different plugins with `re` are not explained in the documentation links I am referring to.

If there's a more thorough documentation for it, you can pinpoint what I am doing wrong in my code, or know how to include the `picard` module in an interpreter (where to find it AND how to include it), then your comments are very much appreciated and valid answers to this question.

Comment: First, are you sure you need a plugin rather than just a [tagger script](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/MusicBrainz_Picard/Documentation/Scripting) here?

Comment: Second, you know about running Picard with the `-d` flag so you can see its output, and/or how to use Python's `logger` module to create your own debugging output in syslogs/a file/whatever, right? Doing one or the other of those is pretty much a necessity for debugging plugins.

Comment: Third, `artist` and `artistsort` are track metadata fields, not album metadata fields, so you will almost certainly want a track processor as well as an album processor.

Comment: Thanks, I missed where the `tagger scritp`s are done when reading the doc. Now it works. I don't know how to run Picard at all. Currently I am using `Options > Options > Plugins > Install plugin...` and see whether it is added to the list or not. Insisting on a plugin version just 'cause I had it written already, adding the fourth argument and changing to album processor did not work either.

Comment: You don't know how to run Picard? Then how did you get to the Options?

Comment: I am working on Windows and didn't figure the name of the executable file called `MusicBrainz Picard` was `picard.exe`. But after trying it out I realized that's what you meant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your biggest problem is that you're mixing up the [plugin API](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/MusicBrainz_Picard/Plugins/API) with the [tagger scripting language](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/MusicBrainz_Picard/Documentation/Scripting).

Tagger scripts are written in a simple custom language; plugins are written in Python. You can't mix and match syntax between the two languages. In particular:

```
match = re.search($not($eq(metadata["albumartistsort"],metadata["albumartist"])))
```

That `$not`, `$eq`, etc. doesn't mean anything in Python. If you want to check whether things are equal, you use the `==` operator. If you want to use `re.search`, you use regular expression syntax. And so on.

Also, your code has to be valid Python, with valid indentation. Your code, at least as posted here.

---

But let's go through your questions one by one:

> I am trying to write a plugin for MusicBrainz that matches the albumartistsort to albumartist and artistsort to artist, as opposed to the (apparently) default of Last Name, First Name format it is currently using.

There are very few automatic defaults in MusicBrainz. Each artist has a name and a sort name, in the database, entered by a human user and verified by other users. You can see this from the web interface. For example, go to [David Bowie](http://musicbrainz.org/artist/5441c29d-3602-4898-b1a1-b77fa23b8e50), and in the "Artist Information" panel on the right side, you'll see "Sort name: Bowie, David". If you're not used to using MusicBrainz's web interface, you should explore it before trying to expand Picard.

> When I try installing the plug in, it doesn't appear in the plugin list although it is copied to the plugin folder; and the .pyo file is not generated. I am guessing this is due to a compilation error

Yep. If you run Picard from the command-line with the `-d` flag, it will *show* you the errors instead of just silently disabling your plugin, so you don't have to guess. This is documented under [Troubleshooting](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/MusicBrainz_Picard/Troubleshooting). (If you're on a Mac, the path will be something like `/Applications/MusicBrainz Picard.app/Contents/MacOS/MusicBrainz Picard`; I think the docs don't explain that because it's standard OS X app bundle stuff.)

> but I haven't been able to include whatever I need so I can use the picard module (don't know where to find it nor import it) so I can test in my python interpreter.

You really can't test it in your interpreter. Picard bundles its own custom-built Python interpreter, rather than using your system Python. In that custom interpreter, the `picard` package is on the `sys.path`, but in your system Python interpreter, it's not. And trying to import that package and use things out of it while not actually running the Picard GUI wouldn't be a good idea anyway.

If you really want to explore what's in the `picard` package, download the source and run a local build of the code. But you really shouldn't need to do that. You shouldn't need any functions beyond those documented in the API, and if you want to debug things, you want to debug them in the right context, which generally means adding `print` functions and/or using the [`logging`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) module in your code.

---

> I must point out that I don't fully understand when these are called.

At some point after each album is downloaded from the MusicBrainz server, all registered album processor functions get called with the album, and all registered track processor function get called with each track on the album.

Notice that an album processor isn't going to be able to change track-level fields like the track artist sort; you will need a track processor for that.

---

> e.g. the search and match methods they use in different plugins with re are not explained in the documentation links I am referring to.

That's because they're part of the Python standard library, which is documented as part of the standard Python docs—in this case, see [`re`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

You're expected to know the basics of Python before being able to write a Picard plugin.

Meanwhile, I'm not sure what you were trying to write here, but it looks like a really convoluted attempt to say "if these two fields aren't equal, make them equal". Which does the same thing as "unconditionally make them equal". So, why even bother with the regexp and the `if` condition?

---

So, your functions could be simplified to:

```
def copy_albumartist_to_albumartistsort(tagger, metadata, release):
    metadata["albumartistsort"] = metadata["albumartist"]

def copy_artist_to_artistsort(tagger, metadata, release, track):
    metadata["artistsort"] = metadata["artist"]

register_album_metadata_processor(copy_albumartist_to_albumartistsort)
register_track_metadata_processor(copy_artist_to_artistsort)
```

---

However, you really don't need a plugin here at all. You should be able to write this whole thing as a trivial tagger script:

```
$set(artistsort,%artist%)
$set(albumartistsort,%albumartist%)
```

Comment: I tried printing the log out calling picard -d from the command line but nothing got printed out (Windows 7). For now I will continue learning python so that I stop making dumb questions. The reason I included the `if` statement was because the direct approach wasn't working on my attempt of plugin. I have a working version just like yours in the `Tagger Script` (thanks for that as well). Thanks for the links, those are answering a lot of questions.

Comment: @Kevin: The documentation admittedly isn't 100% perfect or complete—but really, the best place to get information on the plugin API is probability the [forums](http://forums.musicbrainz.org/viewforum.php?id=2), which luks and voiceinsideyou and other relevant people will usually respond with more detailed and up-to-date information than what you'll find on a general-purpose site like this. And, once you figure something out, you can suggest an update to the plugin docs there (or just edit the wiki version) to help future people.

Comment: @Kevin: Meanwhile, I'm not sure why nothing is getting printed out, but I have one suspicion. IIRC, somewhere around 3 years ago, they added a feature that remembers plugins that fail to load and doesn't try to re-load them at next launch. So, you may have to quit, delete the plugin, possibly bump the version number or delete your prefs, then reinstall the plugin, then `picard -d` again. (The "Advanced method" docs should be all you need to manually uninstall/reinstall plugins.) But it's been almost 3 years since I did any Picard plugin coding, and I never did it on Windows; I could be wrong.

Comment: Erasing the old one did the trick (no need to delete preferences nor close picard)

Comment: @Kevin: Thanks. I had no idea which parts of that shuffle were and weren't necessary; for anyone coming along later, it will be a lot more useful to only know the minimal steps needed instead of my overkill steps.